# Is an Authorize.net Transaction ID unique for all accounts?

Tags: authorize.net

If I have 2 separate authorize.net accounts, is it possible to have two of the same Transaction ID's, one in each of the accounts or is a Transaction ID unique to the entirety of the Authorize.net environment?

Answer (score 2):

Transaction IDs are unique across all payments (e.g.  the entirety of the Authorize.net environment).